# Closedness of subgroup corresponding to semi-simple real Lie subalgebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have an impression (but could be wrong) that I heard that for any semi-simple (real) Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{k}$ of $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ there exists a connected **closed** Lie subgroup $K\subset \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\mathrm{Lie}(K)=\mathfrak{k}$.

Is it correct? A reference would be most helpful.

Comment: Yes: every perfect subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbf{R})$ is even the Lie algebra of a Zariski-closed subgroup. I don't remember the reference.

Comment: What is perfect subalgebra?

Comment: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Perfect_Lie_algebra

Comment: A reference for a comment of @YCor: For any Lie subalgebra ${\mathfrak g}\subset {\mathfrak{gl}}(n,{\mathbb C})$, its derived algebra $[{\mathfrak g},{\mathfrak g}]$ is *algebraic*, that is, it is the Lie algebra of an algebraic subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb C})$. See  Corollary 1 of Theorem 3 in Section 3.3.3 of the book: Onishchik, A. L.; Vinberg, È. B. Lie groups and algebraic groups. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1990.

Comment: If a perfect Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{g}\subset \mathfrak{gl}(n,{\Bbb C})$ is defined over $\Bbb R$, then the corresponding algebraic subgroup is defined over $\Bbb R$ as well.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: In the reference you mentioned I found only the case over complex numbers.

Comment: You should apply this result to the complexification of your Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak k$, and then take the closed Lie subgroup of the $\Bbb R$-points in the corresponding algebraic $\Bbb C$-group *defined over* $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Here’s an old reference for that result due to Yosida (1937): https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1911/44/0/44_0_81/_pdf